# composition method of generating random variables

Tags: random-variables

I'm a student learning about methods for generating random variables.

**But I'm having a hard time finding examples or youtube tutorials on composition method and algorithm of generating random variables.**

Given that this method is grouped with *Acceptance-Rejection* and *inverse transform* in the lecture notes my prof handed out, I'd imagine it is a rather common method. **So I was wondering whether it is referred to with a different name more commonly?** Because I had to no trouble finding examples and tutorials for the A-R and I-T methods.

Obviously my prof's lectures/office hours aren't very helpful and this method isn't even in the textbook. There are no solved examples on this and multiple questions in the homework. Only a single slide in the notes.

[image]

I even searched for different methods of generating RVs (https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generating_random_variables) But it seems to not exist.

Comment: You would use a method such as acceptance-rejection or inverse transform to generate the random variates $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Comment: @Math1000 that is not the question here.  This does not answer my question.

Comment: It does, actually. If you understand how to generate the random variates using the other methods, then the straightforward algorithm that you have posted tells you exactly how to generate a random variate using this method.

Comment: @Math1000 again, that is not the question.  Please refer to the post. I am asking for information on this method.

Comment: @Math1000 your comment does not answer the question stated in the post.

Comment: Try searching for "mixture distribution" then. That's all this is. It seems like you're overthinking this. The algorithm here is very straightforward and cannot be explained any more simply than how you posted it in your question.